# Back Tick Qouted Error in Querying Python Pandas DF

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

Trying to make a def where we have option to select multiple conditions out of the category (column name Current Status)

```
def ft_equal2(key,value2,value1=None):
    return df.query(f'(`{key}`=="{value2}")|(`{key}`=="{value1}")')
ft_equal2("Current Status","Disbursed","Cancelled")
```

gives

UndefinedVariableError: name 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_Current_Status' is not defined

Comment: Column name cannot be inserted as a parameter.

Comment: Same function works with key and value as argument, instead of key, value1 and value2